# Self contained ElectronJS application in linux

Tags: electron

I'm building an electronJS application self-contained. I don't want to have, if it is possible, any dependencies to be installed on the machine. At the moment I'm not able to include libnss3 and libasound2 in the package. I can execute the app if I run the following otherwise not:

apt install libnss3
apt install libasound2

Do you have any advice about how to get rid on this dependencies?
thank you

I tried to create deb package or AppImage package but I'm still running on the same problem

Comment: Huh? If you're packaging the DEB and install it using `dpkg` (or, if possible, `apt`), then all necessary dependencies should be installed automatically. An AppImage should actually include all dependencies necessary to run the application. This *could* be an issue in the software you're using to package the app, like Electron Builder or Electron Forge. Have you looked for similar problem reports against these applications?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.